# Вывод нужного значения

Tags: php, браузер, вывод

Добрый день!

- Нужен совет новичку! Есть таблица в phpmyAdmin "smeny".
- Раньше в нем было только 2 значения: 1 и 2.
  Соответственно, если у врача в поле Monday стоит 1, то в браузере выводит "1 смена", если 2, то выводится 2 смена:

`<?php echo ($smena['monday']==1)?'I смена':'II смена'; ?>`

// если значение == 1 то выводится 1 смена, а иначе 2 смена.

Теперь же мне добавляется еще ТРИ значения: 3 - больничный, 4 - выходной и 5 - отпуск.

Как все пять значений прописать для вывода в браузере, внутри `<?php echo ($smena['monday']==1)?'I смена':'II смена'; ?>`?!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Тут нужно голосовать за ответы и помечать верный.

Comment: Знаю, вот только Репутация моя ниже 15 баллов, так что пока я пас!

Answer (score 1):

Чёнить типа

```
<?php 
echo array(1=>'I смена'
          ,2=>'II смена'
          ,3=>'больничный'
          ,4=>'выходной'
          ,5=>'отпуск'
          )[$smena['monday']];
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ сработал!

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо @Akina за короткий ответ!
В итоге получилось вот так:

- `<td style="background:<?php echo  array(1=>'lightgreen',2=>'pink', 3=>'cyan', 4=>'gold', 5=>'CadetBlue')[$smena['monday']];?>"><?php echo array(1=>'I смена', 2=>'II смена', 3=>'выходной', 4=>'больничный', 5=>'отпуск')[$smena['monday']]; ?></td>`
- Это вместе с окрашиванием нужной ячейки в нужный цвет: value 1 = светло-зеленый и надпись 'I смена' и т.д.

Comment: А зачем дважды одно и то же? разве не работает **_1=>'lightgreen" I смена'_** ?

Comment: А разве можно объединить style и value? Думаю вряд ли получится! Это же разные типы. Или Вы можете привести полную версию <?php echo ..... ?> ???

Comment: При чём тут типы? ты просто выводишь строковые литералы в исходный текст страницы, а уж потом рендер будет весь этот хлам рисовать. Полная версия такая: **<td style="background:<?php echo  array(1=>'lightgreen" I смена',2=>'pink" II смена', 3=>'cyan" выходной', 4=>'gold" выходной', 5=>'CadetBlue" отпуск')[$smena['monday']];?>"></td>**

Comment: Попробовал. все пропало! Т.к.  1) Вы все включили в свойство <td>;   2) Не пойму почему в 'pink" II смена', начинается с одинарных кавычек, потом идут двойные кавычки и заканчиваются опять одинарными?

Comment: Лишняя кавычка была. Поправил: **<td style="background:<?php echo array(1=>'lightgreen" I смена',2=>'pink" II смена', 3=>'cyan" выходной', 4=>'gold" выходной', 5=>'CadetBlue" отпуск')[$smena['monday']];?>></td>**

Comment: @Akina Так и хочется сказать: ВЕК ЖИВИ, ВЕК УЧИСЬ! Но Ваш код также не работает! Цвета меняются, но надписи-то не выведутся если они не написаны между <td> и </td>. Ладно с этим вопросом!  Задал другой вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604236/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment821549_604236 а на меня кодеры въелись!

Comment: Может у Вас есть код графика посещаемости?

Comment: Ну внесите недостающее в литерал, ё моё, что за детсад-то? **<td style="background:<?php echo array(1=>'lightgreen"> I смена',2=>'pink"> II смена', 3=>'cyan"> выходной', 4=>'gold"> выходной', 5=>'CadetBlue"> отпуск')[$smena['monday']];?></td>**

Comment: @Akina Надписи выводятся. только неправильно:       II смена">

Comment: Какие сложности? Поправьте.

Comment: С удовольствием, если бы понял как!  1=>'lightgreen'> I смена', 1=>'lightgreen"=> I смена', 1=>"lightgreen">'I смена'. не срабатывают!